# Rust using iterators methods on env::Args gives errors, maybe a bug?

Tags: rust, iterator

I've been reading the Rust doc, and I finished chapter 13. I updated the minigrep program to use iterators in the Config struct. Now I am trying to re-implement the command line argument using iterators.

What I am trying to do is parse command-line arguments using iterators. Project code:

```
    pub fn new(mut args: env::Args) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        args.next();
        
        let query = match args.next() {
            Some(arg) => arg,
            None => return Err("No query string"),
        };
        
        let filename = match args.next() {
            Some(arg) => arg,
            None => return Err("No Filename"),
        };
        // --snip--
    }
```

I need to compare the first iterator with the optional command-line argument "-c" without consuming the iterator in case the argument is not there.

The first thing I tried was
`args.eq([String::from("-c")].iter());`

But got the error
`` no implementation for `String == &String ``

Next I tried to use
`args.copied().collect();`
got the error
`` expected struct `String`, found reference `` Bug?

Then I tried `args.map(|x: &String| x).collect();`
and got `` expected signature of `fn(String) -> _` ``  Bug?

I tried other methods as well such as: `by_ref, peekable, and cloned`

My question is:

How can I compare the first iterator item of an env::Args to a string without consuming the iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I compare the first iterator item of an `env::Args` to a string without consuming the iterator?

You probably want to use [`Iterator::peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable), which wraps your original iterator into an iterator that offers a method `peek`. That method returns a reference to the next item without advancing (or consuming) the iterator!

```rust
let mut it = args.peekable();
if it.peek().map(|s| s.as_str()) == Some("-a") {
    
}
```

Since `it.peek()` returns `Option<&String>`, I also mapped it to `s.as_str()` to be able to compare it easily to `Some("-a")`, without allocating a `String` for `"-a"`.

Comment: This didn't work. I get the error "move occurs because `args` has type `Args`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait"

Comment: @vis.15 You have to use `it` afterwards, `args` is indeed moved into `it`.

Comment: Why doesn't ```.cloned()``` work on ```env::Args```?

Comment: Because the point of `cloned()` is to convert an `&T` to a `T`, but `Args` is an iterator of `String`s, so already a `T`. Cloning would just duplicate the contents for no reason.